# Could not load type 'XXX' from assembly 'XXX'. at.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

After i have built my model i want to review it so i try to use EntityFramework Power tools to get the model visually , but i get the following error :

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could
>   not load type 'DomainClasses.CompanyLogo' from assembly
>   'DomainClasses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.    at
>   DataLayer.FinanceModelContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext

---

My Domain Class which may cause the error :

```
namespace DomainClasses
{
    public class CompanyLogo
    {
        public byte[] Logo { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Configuration file :

```
public class CompanyLogoMappings:EntityTypeConfiguration<CompanyLogo>
    {
        public CompanyLogoMappings()
        {
            this.HasKey(c => c.CompanyId);
            this.HasRequired(c => c.Company).WithOptional(cl => cl.CompanyLogo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you added CompanyLogoMappings to Configurations?

Comment: @AdilMammadov : yeah `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyLogoMappings());` but  i don't know why this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trails , i find why this error appear.

I added the domain class `CompanyLogo` after i had generated the model through `EF power tools` .

So i **restart the VS** and building the Domain Classes project and run the tool , so it works .